# Saxon genitive question

Tags: translation

Is it correct, from a grammatical point of view, to say "a cats' love"?
Can it be translated as "a love between cats"?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that doesn't really work, due to a combination of these two reasons:

- In general, possessives function as *determiners*, meaning that they play the same sort of role as *a* or *the* or *every*. Just as we never combine *a* with *the* or *every*, we never combine it with a possessive.
- The *-'s* (or *-'*) of a possessive attaches to the entire phrase that it follows, not just to the head noun.

So, for example, "a cat's love" (with singular *cat*) is "{{a cat}'s} love": *-'s* attaches to "a cat", and "a cat's" is the determiner of "love".

That said, sometimes possessives are re-purposed to function as modifiers or complements rather than determiners. When that happens, they are no longer really possessives. For example, we speak of "layman's terms", meaning terms that are commonly used by non-specialists in a subject (as opposed to the "technical terms" that specialists use). In that situation, the determiner is *not* part of the possessive: "this layman's term" means "this {layman's term}", not "{this layman}'s term". Similarly, "a women's dressing room" means "a {women's {dressing room}}", not "{{a women}'s} {dressing room}".

?"A cats' love" does not have any conventionalized meaning with *cats'* being repurposed in this way, but I think it's at least possible. For example, I could imagine a fantasy short story about Cupid giving out "loves" to various animals, and accidentally giving "a cats' love" (=a love intended for cats) to a pair of dogs.

In any event, it would *not* mean "a love between cats".

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is very clear and informative... and the Cupid example is awesome :)

Comment: @DavideLaVardera: You're welcome!